# DEFLATED data will always be larger than the uncompressed input data

Tags: c++, zlib

I'm now trying to understand how deflate and **inflate** work
Here is a simple program with **dummyFields** struct.

```
// Here i give a total memory size for the output buffer used by deflate func
#define CHUNK 16384

struct dummyFields
{
    long a;
    char b;
    long c;
    float d;
    float e;
    float f;
    float g;
    float h;
    char i;
    unsigned int j;
};

Bytef *dataOriginal = (Bytef*)malloc( sizeof(dummyFields) );
Bytef *dataCompressed = (Bytef*)malloc( CHUNK );

z_stream s
s.zalloc = Z_NULL;
s.zfree = Z_NULL;
s.opaque = Z_NULL;
deflateInit(&s, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);

s.avail_out = CHUNK;
s.next_out = dataCompressed;

int compressSize = 0;
int decompSize = 0;
dummyFields para;

    // set all values equals to 0
    memset( &para, 0, sizeof(dummyFields) );
    //Inserts value in struct fields
    para.a = 31272;
    para.b = 'z';
    para.c = 66.54;
    para.e = 123;
    para.f = 66.54;
    .
    .
    para.j = 123;
    //copy this values in a Bytef* elements
    memcpy( dataOriginal, &para, sizeof(dummyFields));

    s.avail_in = sizeof(dummyFields);
    s.next_in = dataOriginal;

    int response = deflate(&s, Z_FINISH);

    //don't get any errors here
    if( res == Z_STREAM_END ){
        compressSize = CHUNK - s.avail_out;
    }
}
deflateEnd(&s);

//here I get 45 byte but actual struct sizeof is 40.
printf("Total bytes after compress %d\n",compressSize); 

// Trying to get back my data
Bytef *decomp = (Bytef*)malloc( sizeof(Particle) );

z_stream s_inflate;
s_inflate.zalloc = Z_NULL;
s_inflate.zfree = Z_NULL;
s_inflate.opaque = Z_NULL;
inflateInit(&s_inflate);

// data i want to get at the next inflate
s_inflate.avail_in = spaceUsed;
s_inflate.next_in = dataCompressed;

s_inflate.avail_out = sizeof(dummyFields);
s_inflate.next_out = decomp;

int response = inflate( &s_inflate, Z_NO_FLUSH );

if( res == Z_STREAM_END ){
        decompSize = CHUNK - s.avail_out;
}
//Here I got 40 bytes which is correct beacuse actual struct size is 40
printf("Total bytes after compress %d\n",decompSize);
inflateEnd( &s_inflate );

dummyFields data;
memset( &data, 0, sizeof(data) );
memcpy( &data, decomp, sizeof(data));
```

when I tried to back my data from the inflate response I get actual values(whic h is correct). Deflate and Inflate functions work fine.

When i try to find the size of`(sizeof(dummyFields))` the struct it give me 40 bytes

**Problem**

- Actual size of struct is 40 when I compress the data it give me 45
  bytes how it is possible ?
- My requirement data is 30 to 40 bytes is there any another library
  which will compress the data 10 to 20 bytes(when I give 30 to 40 bytes)?
- Is there some way to GUARANTEE that the output compressed data will
  be SMALLER than the input data?

**Note**

When I increase number of struct fields or size of data 40 to 100 bytes compression result is Ok.
When I decrease number of fields or size 100 bytes to 40 bytes compression result is not Good

Comment: Please provide a true [mcve].

Comment: Dupe answered by the originator of zlib himself.

Answer (score 3):

There is no GUARANTEE that output compressed data will be SMALLER. Compression implies some overhead for storing some structural information describing the data being packed (like dictionary in primitive case) that allows to represent the data using less space. You may get a larger compressed output for a single compressed structure, but you most likely will get a much smaller compressed output for an array of these structures (especially when they are not very different from each other).

If your compressed output turns out to be larger that uncompressed then just store an uncompressed version.